# Getting rid of outdated versions of Ruby gems and keep current versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

For the `devise` gem I have multiple different versions and want to get rid of them, but I also want to keep the current version of `devise` and not have to reinstall it.

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.0)
devise (4.3.0, 4.2.1, 4.2.0, 3.5.10)
drip (0.0.2)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.7.7)
minitest (4.3.2)
psych (2.0.0)
rake (0.9.6)
rbtree (0.4.1)
rdoc (4.0.0)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
```

how can I go about doing it without messing things up?

Comment: The other gems are fine it is just the devise gem that needs work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is sample to remove specific version of gem

```
gem uninstall devise --version 4.2.1
# uninstall older version
gem uninstall devise --version '<4.3.0'
```

Comment: Do I have to do that for every version or is there a command that will just get rid of all the old ones except for the most recent version?